# Marker Interface To avoid Generic Controllers & Constructor with generic paramaters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, marker-interfaces

I have overridden default IdentityUser and UserStore provided by Microsoft Identity.

```
    public class ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey, TClientKey> : IdentityUser<TIdentityKey>, IApplicationUser<TIdentityKey, TClientKey>
    where TIdentityKey : IEquatable<TIdentityKey>
    where TClientKey : IEquatable<TClientKey>
    {
        public TClientKey TenantId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserStore<TUser, TRole, TIdentityKey, TClientKey> : UserStore<TUser, TRole, IdentityServerDbContext<TIdentityKey, TClientKey>, TIdentityKey>
    where TUser : ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey, TClientKey>
    where TRole : ApplicationRole<TIdentityKey>
    where TIdentityKey : IEquatable<TIdentityKey>
    where TClientKey : IEquatable<TClientKey>
    {
        private readonly IdentityServerDbContext<TIdentityKey, TClientKey> _context;
        private readonly ITenantService<TIdentityKey, TClientKey> _tenantService;
        public ApplicationUserStore(IdentityServerDbContext<TIdentityKey, TClientKey> context, ITenantService<TIdentityKey, TClientKey> tenantService) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _tenantService = tenantService;
        }
        public async override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            user.TenantId = await GetTenantId();
            bool combinationExists = await _context.Users
            .AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == user.UserName
                        && x.Email == user.Email
                        && x.TenantId.Equals(user.TenantId));
    
            if (combinationExists)
            {
                var IdentityError = new IdentityError { Description = "The specified username and email are already registered" };
                return IdentityResult.Failed(IdentityError);
            }
    
            return await base.CreateAsync(user);
        }
        
        private async Task<TClientKey> GetTenantId()
        {
            var tenant = await _tenantService.GetCurrentTenant();
            if (tenant == null)
                return default(TClientKey);
            else
                return tenant.Id;
        }
    }
```

I have made these inside a class library and imported into different projects. So that I can provide different Keys for user such as Guid, int, string based on project needs. The problem I am facing is that when I try to use these in Identity Pages such as ConfirmPassword Page I need to specify Generic in model so that I can control it using dependency injection.

```
    public class ConfirmEmailModel<TIdentityKey,TClientKey> : PageModel
    where TIdentityKey:IEqutable<TIdentityKey>
    where TClientKey:IEqutable<TClientKey>
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>> _userManager;

        public ConfirmEmailModel (UserManager<ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [TempData]
        public virtual string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }

            code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
            StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

When I specify Generic Type like this. I cant use it inside razor pages as razor pages does not support generic types.

```
@page
@model ConfirmEmailModel<T>// SYNTAX ERROR
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Confirm email";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
```

Other problem is when I try to use SignInManager or UserStore inside controller. I again cant use dependency injection to inject generics in places

```
Public class BaseUserInfoController<TIdentityKey,TClientKey> : Controller
where TIdentityKey:IEqutable<TIdentityKey>
where TClientKey:IEqutable<TClientKey>

    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>> _userManager;

        public BaseUserInfoController(UserManager<ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>> userManager)
            => _userManager = userManager;

        //
        // GET: /api/userinfo
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [HttpGet("~/connect/userinfo"), HttpPost("~/connect/userinfo"), Produces("application/json")]
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Userinfo()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Challenge(
                    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidToken,
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] =
                            "The specified access token is bound to an account that no longer exists."
                    }));
            }

            var claims = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
            {
                // Note: the "sub" claim is a mandatory claim and must be included in the JSON response.
                [Claims.Subject] = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user)
            };

            if (User.HasScope(Scopes.Email))
            {
                claims[Claims.Email] = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
                claims[Claims.EmailVerified] = await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);
            }

            if (User.HasScope(Scopes.Phone))
            {
                claims[Claims.PhoneNumber] = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
                claims[Claims.PhoneNumberVerified] = await _userManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user);
            }

            if (User.HasScope(Scopes.Roles))
            {
                //claims[Claims.Role] = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                List<string> roles = new List<string> { "dataEventRecords", "dataEventRecords.admin", "admin", "dataEventRecords.user" };
            }

            // Note: the complete list of standard claims supported by the OpenID Connect specification
            // can be found here: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims

            return Ok(claims);
        }

    }
```

For another service I have written an IUnitOfWork. To use this IUnitOfWork inside a controller. I again need to specify all the keys inside a controller.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<TRoleKey, TUserKey, TClientKey> : IDisposable
        where TRoleKey : IEquatable<TRoleKey>
        where TUserKey : IEquatable<TUserKey>
        where TClientKey : IEquatable<TClientKey>
    {
        IUserService<TRoleKey, TUserKey, TClientKey> UserService { get; }
        IRoleService<TRoleKey, TUserKey, TClientKey> RoleService { get; }
        IUserRoleService<TRoleKey, TUserKey, TClientKey> UserRoleService { get; }
        IRolePermissionService<TRoleKey, TUserKey, TClientKey> RolePermissionService { get; }

        Task<bool> Commit();
    }
```

To solve all of these issues. I was thinking to using MarkerInterfaces for all these different services. Like for example for using ApplicationUser.

```
public interface IMarkerApplicationUser{}



public class ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey, TClientKey> : IMarkerApplicationUser,IdentityUser<TIdentityKey>, IApplicationUser<TIdentityKey, TClientKey>
    where TIdentityKey : IEquatable<TIdentityKey>
    where TClientKey : IEquatable<TClientKey>
    {
        
        public TClientKey TenantId { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Afterwards I can just take these as constructor parameter and use dependency injection to specify generic instead of GenericType functions and classes.

```
services.AddScoped<IMarkerApplicationUser, ApplicationUser<Guid,Guid>>();
```

Is this a good approach? I have read every where that using marker interfaces is a bad practice.

The main purpose of doing all this is to create generic microservices for my common projects. Like UserManagement, RoleManagement, Audit Management, Exception Management and then pass the type of keys from the main project. I don't want to use GUID everywhere as the primary keys because, some of the systems doesn't have the requirement to use Guid and have space constraints.

Comment: Well, yes, a market interface is bad-practice. But if you give it some commonly used properties, you just end up with a normal interface which is fine, Just make sure you're not rebuilding the full userstore and such.

Comment: @Stefan What different will it make if I leave it empty or just add some properties without any certain reason? what will be the use of those properties?

Comment: If you use interface wrappers you'll might be able to fix the razor generic type issue as well.. not sure though

Comment: @Stefan what's the difference between interface wrapper and marker interface? are both the same?

Comment: the interface "wrapper" wraps common logic and lets you deal with different implementations... the tricky part is to resolve the correct one, so I am not sure it will help your case

Comment: @Stefan there is not much common logic in my case. I just need to avoid specifying TKey's every where like in controllers and other models. Just specify them in one place using dependency injection. I cant think of any other way than using MarkerInterfaces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247683/discussion-between-safi-mustafa-and-stefan).

Comment: For the record, [I don't think marker interfaces are evil](https://www.matthewathomas.com/programming/2022/09/08/marker-interface-not-evil.html)

Answer (score 0):

## `ConfirmEmailModel` does not need to be generic

These are the only things I can see that are affected by the generic type
parameters in `ConfirmEmailModel`:

- The return type of `_userManager.FindByIdAsync(...)`
- The type of the `user` variable in `OnGetAsync(...)`
- The type of the `user` parameter in `_userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, ...)`

(Also, `user` has to be a nullable reference type for your null check)

You don't need generic type parameters to make these pieces fit together. What
if your `ConfirmEmailModel` instead looked like the following?

```cs
public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
{
    readonly IUserManager _userManager;

    public ConfirmEmailModel(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [TempData]
    public virtual string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }

        code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
        StatusMessage = result.Succeeded
            ? "Thank you for confirming your email."
            : "Error confirming your email.";
        return Page();
    }
}

public interface IUserManager
{
    Task<Result> ConfirmEmailAsync(object user, string code);

    Task<object?> FindByIdAsync(string userId);
}

sealed class UserManagerAdapter : IUserManager
{
    readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>> _userManager;

    public UserManagerAdapter(UserManager<ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<Result> ConfirmEmailAsync(object user, string code)
    {
        if (user is not ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey> applicationUser)
            return Fail();
        return await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(applicationUser, code);
    }

    public async Task<object?> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        return await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    }
}
```

Then you could wire up your IoC registrations in such a way that the
`UserManagerAdapter` is the registered implementation of `IUserManager`.

## `BaseUserInfoController` also does not need to be generic

You can apply a similar way of thinking to `BaseUserInfoController`.

What are the generic type parameters actually used for?

To me it seems that the only thing that really cares what type the `user`
variable is, is the very same `_userManager` that gave it to you in the first
place. That raises a little warning flag in my head that says "implementation
detail". From the perspective of your `BaseUserInfoController` it doesn't matter
what that type is, so what's the point of the generic type parameters? If
`_userManager` just returned opaque `object`s then you could lose the generic
type parameters and your `BaseUserInfoController` would be no worse off.

## Leaky abstractions

I think your abstractions are kind of leaky (Google the phrase "leaky
abstraction"). Generic type parameters in your case are an implementation
detail—not even your model and controller care what they are—and yet
everything that uses your model or controller has to deal with those details.

What I'm proposing instead is that you hide those implementation details behind
interfaces that are tailored to the consumers of those interfaces.

I hope this helps!

<sub>The above code was written off the cuff and might not compile</sub>

Comment: That's why I am asking If I should be using Marker Interface. That way I don't need to pass around Generic Types every where instead of an object. I don't think it's that leaky to know that you need to pass type of ApplicationUser is not a bad thing I am not giving away whats going on inside a repository. You just need specify your objects and it will do what it is intended to do under the hood or you can have an option to override it.

Comment: @SafiMustafa I think you can do all those things by putting the user _manager_ behind an interface. Remember: tailor interfaces to consumers. E.g. what interface signatures are needed by `ConfirmEmailModel`? (cont'd)

Comment: @SafiMustafa With respect to the user, I think the answer is "ConfirmEmailModel doesn't need an interface at all" (because ConfirmEmailModel doesn't ever call into the user object... all it needs to know is that it's a nullable `object`). But with respect to the user _manager_, `ConfirmEmailModel` needs to call a couple of methods. So put the user _manager_ behind an interface, then things are simple--all the generics go away :)

Comment: @SafiMustafa About marker interfaces specifically: I've found them useful when I need to introduce a hierarchy into the type system but don't need any common behavior. For example, I could make `interface IReportModel { }` and then implement that interface on all the models in a reflection-based report generation system. Then my report generator can have a function with this signature: `public Report Generate(IReportModel model)` instead of this signature: `public Report Generate(object model)`. The marker interface is a hint to everyone that those types (not any object) are for my framework

Comment: I guess you are suggesting Adapter Pattern to me. Let me do some research on that.

Comment: @SafiMustafa Basically. Tailoring interfaces to consumers often leads to adapter pattern because it tends to increase the number of interfaces, and they tend to cloud around each individual consumer. Then adapters become necessary to give outside stuff the shape the consumer expects. Bonus: C# doesn't allow you to implement interfaces for foreign types (e.g. I can't make `System.String` implement a new interface), but some other languages do (e.g. Rust with its trait system), and thus there's less boilerplate in those languages to do "the right thing" with interfaces.

Comment: @SafiMustafa (cont'd) So I guess in this specific case, yes adapter pattern is what you want. But the general rule is "tailor interfaces to consumers". A lot of other problems go away when you stick to that general rule, and it applies more broadly than to just C# `interface`. For example, when you apply that rule to HTTP API endpoints serving multiple businesses then you get one HTTP endpoint per business which keeps each business's rules from coming into direct contact with another business in your code... saves a lot of headaches. I find that the general rule naturally helps with SOLID code

Comment: I have read about adapter patter. But, I am still confused how will this work over here. In the example you have provided . You have used  UserManager<ApplicationUser<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>> in UserManagerAdapter. How will TIdentityKey and TClient key will be resolved? If I again specify them as Generic Types then we are back to square one.

Comment: @SafiMustafa Good catch. It should be `sealed class UserManagerAdapter<TIdentityKey,TClientKey>`. Then the type parameters are specified when you instantiate the `UserManagerAdapter` e.g. `IUserManager userManagerAdapter = new UserManagerAdapter<Foo, Bar>(new UserManager<ApplicationUser<Foo,Bar>>(...));`. Then you give the `IUserManager` instance to your controllers/models. Note: how you instantiate the adapter will depend on if/what IoC framework you're using, but that's the basic idea

Comment: It wont work with Adapter as well. You have used object in IUserManager. What about IUnitOfWork. How will we handle that?